# Div are not hiding using javascript in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to show a div when an error occurs and hide when everything is okay but the div is not hiding and showing with JavaScript.

My code is as follows:

```
<script>
  function hideerror() {
    var catdiv = document.getElementById(error);
    catdiv.style.display = "none";
  }
</script>

<div class="form-item">
  <div id="error" class="hideerror" style="color:#F00">
    error occured
  </div>
</div>



<?php   
  echo '<script type="text/javascript"> hideerror(); </script>';  
?>
```

Comment: you can do like this also - `$('#error').hide()`

Comment: what is the purpose of this `echo '<script type=...` ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it like this?

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Test Page</title>
  </head>
 <body>
   <button type='button' onclick='showHideErrors()' id='btnShow'>
   <div id='error' style='display:none;'>
     Error occured
   </div>

 <script type='text/javascript'>
    function showHideErrors(){
       if($('#error').is(':visible'){
         $('#error').hide();
       }else{
         $('#error').show();
       }
    }

</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to quote the ID in the `getElementById` call:

```
var catdiv = document.getElementById('error');
//                                   ^     ^ quotes
```

Without the quotes, `error` is treated as a variable (which is undefined).

For future debugging, observe your browser's console (F12). This will be emitting an error relating to `catdiv` being undefined/not an object.